# while streaming video file, file is getting locked by another process using PushStreamContent..how to solve it

Tags: asp.net-web-api, video-streaming, pushstreamcontent

I am trying to stream video file . when i open the same video file in another tab of browser , i get the message "file is being used by another process" . if I use FileShare.ReadWrite in file.open method then error goes away but video doesn't play in browser . can someone pl. help .

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([string id)
        {
            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"] + "/" + id);
            var video = new VideoStream(path);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
            var contentType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Path.GetExtension(id)];
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent(video.WriteToStream,  new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType));

            return response;
        }


        public class VideoStream
        {
            private readonly string _filename;

            public VideoStream(string filename)
            {
                _filename = filename;
            }


            public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[65536];

                    using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        var length = (int) video.Length;
                        var bytesRead = 1;

                        while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                             await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            length -= bytesRead;
                            video.Flush();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpException ex)
                {
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {


                 //   outputStream.Close();
                  //  outputStream.Flush();
                }
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:
    File.Open(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

Assuming the file lock comes from the server. Is that the case, or is it a client side thing?

Comment: i have tried all the given options for fileshare but nothing works. i get the same black screen every time.

Comment: if  you have access to the server you might want to look at filemon and see what process is holding on to the file and see if it's your own app or something else. 

Also you didn't answer where the message comes from - Is it from the client or on the server.

Comment: thanks Yishai to look for my issue! i have added file locally in my project to debug this  so that there is no other process running on server cause this. the reason is that video file is big so when the video is still playing and i tried to open file using File.open for another tab in browser , it causes this error message or black screen depends on fileshare is being added or not. it's on server side.

Comment: can you paste the exception, and verify the file name that is locked is the video file name and not another file?

Comment: I got a few other comments idea:
1. Note that there is no reason to use push stream here, if you get the video from a file, you know where it's coming from and you know the length upfront. Push stream is for scenarios where you get an open stream from an unknown source and you push it down to your client. I don't think that the source of your issue though, just a design issue.
2. Note that you are really just downloading a file and not streaming video, there is no way with what you are doing to index into the middle of the video
3. Look for Anti virus locking your file, perhaps disable to test

Comment: removed the push stream method and added very simple code

Comment: if i added fileaccess.share, then i get no exception but video doesn't play in 2 browsers , i am using webapi fraework4.0 . video is playing fine in one tab  but as soon as I try to play in another tab, it just stuck, doing nothing at all. and it is html5 browser issue, mainly i am testing in chrome.